# Can I force a compiler error if certain functions are not called?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727418), I'd like to know whether there is  any trick (like SFINAE) to achieve the opposite.

**Edit: Adding example**

I have something like this (it is very simplified because it has a lot of details):

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  Base(){}
  virtual ~Base(){
  }
  void initialize() { implementation(); }
private:
  virtual void implementation() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
  virtual void implementation() { std::cout << "initialization" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {

  std::unique_ptr<Base> b(new Derived());
  b->initialize();

  return 0;
}
```

The initialize method **must** be called.

But if I put initialize method inside Base constructor it will call a pure virtual method.
I want to know if there is a way to prevent someone to use improperly the constructed object.

**Edit: My "solution":**

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base(){
  }
  Base() {};
private:
  void initialize() { implementation(); }
  virtual void implementation() = 0;
  template<class DerivedType> friend Base *factory();
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
  Derived() {}
  virtual void implementation() { std::cout << "initialization" << std::endl;}
  template<class DerivedType> friend Base *factory();
};

template<class DerivedType>
static Base *factory(){
  Base *b = new DerivedType();
  b->initialize();
  return b;
}

int main() {

  std::unique_ptr<Base> b(factory<Derived>());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit speculative/rhetorical.  Do you have a practical use case?

Comment: There are tools that detect unreachable code.

Comment: It is impossible for the general case to cause a *compiler* error. You can only tell whether for sure whether a function will or will not be called by running the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force a compiler error, but there are other alternatives.

If an instance of your type is simply invalid unless initialize is called, and if documenting that fact or throwing an exception upon use if uninitialized is unacceptable, then you should make the constructor private and expose a static method to create instances of your type.

This way clients of your code simply cannot use an uninitialized instance of your type.  If there is a better, more elegant approach I don't know of it (but maybe someone around here does).

Comment: This is what I did, my factory class is friend of my instance.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this should not be required because when you create an object, that object can initialize itself properly without having to call an initialization function.

This may sound strange, but in most cases that `initialization()` function is not proper:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { do initialization of A fields here; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() { do initialization of B fields here; }
};
```

That should be sufficient in most cases.

If you pass a parameter to the constructor, you may need some interfaces (to not create loops in your #include) and then you just pass those parameters around as in:

```
class C;
class D;

class A
{
public:
    A(C c) { do initialization of A fields here; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(C c, D d) : A(c) { do initialization of B fields here; }
};
```

Otherwise, to verify at run time, [boost](http://www.boost.org/) and my [controlled_vars](https://sourceforge.net/projects/controlled-vars/) (templates to make types such as int safe, finally!) offer facilities to check whether a field was initialized and it can either throw and return a default value.

I'm otherwise not aware of any facility in the compiler to do such a test. However, if you write a test (you should always have tests anyway!) then your test can do such verifications.

Note that I first thought of a profiler, but that requires a test which will anyway tell you whether you are correct or not and the profiler could show you that the initialization was called, but you wouldn't know whether that happened in all cases.

However, to really enforce such initialization at compile time (assuming you really need it), as mentioned by Ed S., the best is probably to use a factory. That way all the ugly initialization code remains hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't remember which was the specific case that I needed something like that. I agree with you, all initialization must be done at the ctor or using a creational pattern.

Comment: Yes. I'm working on a system where I load plugins from .so files. That initialization does not work hand in hand with C++ and as a result I also have some `init()` function. Yet in many cases we, programmers, do it wrong... From time to time I catch myself adding a useless initialization function!