# Force Linker Error on Function Call To Library

Tags: c++, linker

I would like to force an error or warning if I call a certain function from a third-party lib because I want to avoid needing reviews to make sure we do not call that function.

Google gives me very old StackOverflow answers to that problem at the top (e.g. [Can I force a compiler error if certain functions are called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727418/can-i-force-a-compiler-error-if-certain-functions-are-called)) which are based on adding #defines or #deprecated hints in the code which are based on preprocessing, but to avoid any weird issues with the naming there I was wondering whether there is any modern possibility to actually tell the *linker* that I want to link against library libfoo, but please error out if someone in my code links against a specific call in libfoo.

**NOTE**: This is *not* meant as a security protection against a malevolent actor, I only want to automate the process of detecting that we call that function by accident.

Comment: Did you try making a copy of the library's header file where the function is declared, removing the declaration and putting the altered header's directory first in the compiler's search path for includes?

Comment: ^ or at least mark them as `deprecated` to get warnings automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are many ways of doing that.

If you want to do this during *compile time*, before runtime, you can use `static_assert(condition, message)`. This is the the cleanest and modernist way thus far. Here is some info on that: [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-static_assert-c-11/). It is pure C++, no library necessary.

Example:

```
void foo(int a)
{
    static_assert(a > 5, "Too big!");
}
```

If you want to get it during runtime, you can throw exceptions `throw runtime_error("Example");`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use attributes `deprecated` or `warning("message")` to diagnose this at compile time:

```
$ cat tmp.c
__attribute__((warning("do not use me"))) void foo() {}

int main() { foo(); return 0; }

$ gcc tmp.c
tmp2.c: In function ‘main’:
tmp2.c:2:14: warning: call to ‘foo’ declared with attribute warning: do not use me [-Wattribute-warning]
```

This is a preferred approach as it will allow to diagnose errors early and with precise source code location.

On Linux you can also use a `.gnu.warning` section to emit warning at link time:

```
$ cat foo.c
void foo() {}

static const char foo_warning[] __attribute__((used,section(".gnu.warning.foo"))) = "do not use me";

$ cat main.c
void foo();

int main() { foo(); return 0; }

$ gcc foo.c main.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPfdczm.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xe): warning: do not use me
```